# Cocoa Scripting: Getting the index of a scriptable object in its container

Tags: applescript, cocoa-scripting

Given a scriptable object's `NSScriptObjectSpecifier`, how do I tell the index of object(s) in their container?

I cannot find any accessor method for that in the `NSScriptObjectSpecifier` or its subclasses.

If the object is a `NSIndexSpecifier`, it's easy to get the index. But if it's something else, e.g. a `NSNameSpecifier`, then it needs to be inquired. The Cocoa Scripting guide says that the framework does that automatically when *it* needs to learn the index, but it's not explained how that's done.

There is the method `indicesOfObjectsByEvaluatingObjectSpecifier` a scriptable object can implement to return such indices, but that's an optional method, and so I assume I cannot simply invoke that on any scriptable object.

Is there some other easy way to learn the index, or do I have to implement my own method that walks down the specifiers and handles all the possible cases on its own?

Comment: Have you implemented `-objectIn<Key>AtIndex:`?

Comment: Yes. How would that help? I don't want to have to get all items and then search them for the object in question. That'd lead to quite a bad performance.

Comment: Then I don't understand the question. For any subclass in the hierarchy you have to provide a `NSScriptObjectSpecifier` containing the `containerClassDescription`. From that specifier the framework can identify the proper index.

Comment: I need the inverse function: I know the specifier and want to know its index, thru Cocoa Scripting. As the specifier may point to any number of different classes, I cannot query the objects directly unless I'd extend each of them with my own protocol to return their index in their container. That's overkill, IMHO. I need this in order to be able to tell if an array of such specifiers is in order (needed for creating NSRangeSpecifier, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239287), though the suggestion in your 1st comment would help identifying the indices, but it'll be slow with large lists

Comment: @vadian If you put your comment into an answer, I'll upvote it (though it won't be the accepted answer because it doesn't answer the question completely, i.e. how to return a non-consecutive list).

Comment: No, thanks, it's indeed more a comment than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for NSArray's

```
- indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:self
```

by any chance? I use this in an -objectSpecifier method when I need to return a formIndex ospec.